# encyrpt a key with setted RSA public key in java

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption

i'm triying encrypt a password. firstly i will set a rsa public key, after encyrpt a password. but my results are not equals between java and javascript code. is there a way or sample. Could you help me? thanks.

here is my javascript code

```
var rsa = new RSAKey();
rsa.setPublic(rasn, rase);
var res = rsa.encrypt("myPassword");
return restotal;
```

here is my java code

```
RSA1 rsa = new RSA1(new BigInteger(rasn.getBytes()),new BigInteger(rase.getBytes()));    
String text1 = "myPassword";
BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger(text1.getBytes());
BigInteger ciphertext = rsa.encrypt(plaintext);
System.out.println(ciphertext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your `RSA1` class exactly does, but you can check a nice sample [here](https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/rsa-encryption-example/).

Your results will **never** be same, because before RSA encryption, your data will be appended with random bytes called [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Public_key_cryptography).

If you want to test your encryption, decrypt the result back with your private key and see if it works. You can do this between javascript and java if you wish.

Comment: thank you for reply, i try execute a post method from java to my modem interface, the modem generate 2 variable n and e. when it creates public key use them, i get them and generate a encrypted password in my java code.  so both of them have to be same havent it? but i couldnot convert javascript rsa to java rsa

Comment: @enes I am not sure what are you trying to acomplish. Do you generate the keypair in `javascript` and than you want to use the public key to encrypt a password in client java? What do you mean by *rsa*, keys, encrypted message or something else? You need to be more specific.